# Combine two list elements into single element

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with two elements

element 1:

```
no:1,
vendor: a,
Description: Nice,
price :10
```

element 2:

```
no:1
vendor:a,
Description: Nice,
price:20
```

i have lot more fields in list elements so i cannot use new to sum the price

if everything is same except price i need to combine two elements into a single element by summing price.

o/p  element 1:

```
               no:1,
               vendor:a,
               Description:Nice,
               price:30
```

Tried below one but not sure how to sum the price and return the entire fields with out using new

```cs
list.GroupBy(y => new { y.Description,y.vendor, y.no})
    .Select(x => x.ToList().OrderBy(t => t.Price)).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Looks like `GroupBy` can do that. What did you try so far? :)

Comment: ... and what is the actual problem with doing that? Please **[edit]** the question and show what code you tried.

Comment: Oh I see, you want to know if you can group a list by *all the fields but one* in an easy way?

Comment: Can you check this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432086/getting-difference-between-two-objects-with-same-properties] or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224156/using-linq-to-get-the-difference-between-two-list-of-objects-based-only-on-a-sin] and run a loop on those with similar property values except price. So you will have 2 lists of one with same price and another with different property values. After this you will have to join the 2 lists

Comment: If I aimed right reading your question, you might update it and explain that you're looking for something like `GroupByAllBut(y => y.price)` instead of having to write `GroupBy(y => new { [excessive amount of properties] })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Element> elements = new List<Element>() {
                new Element() { no = 1, vendor = "a", Description =  "Nice", price = 10},
                new Element() { no = 1, vendor = "a", Description =  "Nice", price = 20}
            };

            List<Element> totals = elements.GroupBy(x => x.no).Select(x => new Element()
            {
                no = x.Key,
                vendor = x.FirstOrDefault().vendor,
                Description = x.FirstOrDefault().Description,
                price = x.Sum(y => y.price)
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Element
    {
        public int no { get;set; }
        public string vendor { get;set; }
        public string Description { get;set; }
        public decimal price { get;set; }
    }
```

Try following using Clone

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Element> elements = new List<Element>() {
                new Element() { no = 1, vendor = "a", Description =  "Nice", price = 10},
                new Element() { no = 1, vendor = "a", Description =  "Nice", price = 20}
            };

            var groups = elements.GroupBy(x => x.no).ToList();
            List<Element> totals = new List<Element>();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                Element newElement = (Element)group.FirstOrDefault().Clone();
                newElement.price = group.Sum(x => x.price);
                totals.Add(newElement);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Element : ICloneable 
    {
        public int no { get;set; }
        public string vendor { get;set; }
        public string Description { get;set; }
        public decimal price { get;set; }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hello jdweng i have lot of fields to return so i dont want to use new , is there any other way

Comment: You would have to use a for loop and use clone.  Then only change the one that are different (if any).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom `IEqualityComparer`, which when passed into the `GroupBy` clause, will group the items according to your needs.

Asuming the following sample class:

```
public class Element
{
    public int no { get; set; }
    public string vendor { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
}
```

You can implement the following `IEqualityComparer` which using `Reflection` will compare every `Property`present in the `Element` class except the ones defined in the Linq `Where` clause, in this case `"price"`. Bear in mind further customizations could be required.

```
public class ElementComparer : IEqualityComparer<Element>
{
    public bool Equals(Element a, Element b) => typeof(Element).GetProperties()
                                           .Where(p => p.Name != "price")
                                           .All(p => p.GetValue(a).Equals(p.GetValue(b)));

    public int GetHashCode(Element obj) => obj.no.GetHashCode();
}
```

Then simply group them this way

```
list.GroupBy(x => x, new ElementComparer()).Select(g =>
{
    // Here you need to either clone the first element of the group like
    // @jdweng did, or create a new instance of Element like I'm doing below

    Element element = new Element();
    foreach (var prop in element.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.Name == "price")
        {
            prop.SetValue(element, g.Sum(y => y.price));
        }
        else
        {
            prop.SetValue(element, prop.GetValue(g.First()));
        }                   
    }
    return element;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Willy-nilly you have to create `Key` which has `3` properties;

If you don't like the current solution with *anonymous class*

```
list
  .GroupBy(y => new { 
     y.Description,
     y.vendor, 
     y.no}
   )
  ...
```

You can do it in different way, e.g. with a help of *unnamed tuple*:

```
list
  .GroupBy(y => Tuple.Create(
     y.Description, 
     y.vendor, 
     y.no)
   )
  ...
```

Or *named tuple* (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples for details):

```
list
  .GroupBy(y => (
     Description : y.Description,
     vendor      : y.vendor, 
     no          : y.no)
   )
  ...
```

Or even *tailored class*. What's matter the most, however, is that you can't just *get* `First` item from the `group`
but should *create a new instance*. Another issue is *premature materialization*: `.ToList()` when you then get rid of this new born list and keep on *querying* with `.OrderBy(...)`

```
var result = result
  .GroupBy(y => new { 
     y.Description,
     y.vendor, 
     y.no}
   )
  .Select(group => MyObject() { //TODO: put the right syntax here
      Description = group.Key.Description,
      vendor      = group.Key.vendor,   
      no          = group.Key.no,  
      price       = group.Sum(item => item.price) // you want to sum prices, right?
     });
```

Comment: I think that OP is looking for something like `GroupByAllBut(y => y.price)`

Comment: @Rafalon: "if *everything is same* except price", it seems to me quite the opposite - we should group by all the properies *except* `price` which we should `sum`

Comment: That's why I wrote Group by **all but** price. I'm not native but I think that's what *all but* means, right? If not, then read it as `GroupByEverythingExcept(y => y.price)`

Comment: @Rafalon: I see: `GroupByAllBut`, sorry, I've *misread* your comment

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer LINQ query expressions:

```
var groupedElements = from element in elements
    group element by new
    {
        element.no,
        element.Description,
        element.vendor
    }
    into grouped
    select new {grouped, TotalPrice = grouped.Sum(x => x.price)};
```

The total price is calculated with the final `.Sum` method call on the grouped elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is write dynamic code that groups by all properties *except* for the property you want to sum. This solution should work, though I loath to use reflection. A more performant method would be to use expression trees to generate an aggregation delegate that you reuse, but that is very involved. This should do the trick:

Edit: There's another answer that also seems to work. Mine assumes you will want to do this with any collection regardless of type. Doesn't require `ICloneable` or a type-specific `IEqualityComparer<T>`, though, as a slight trade-off, the other one will likely perform better in very large datasets.

```
static T[] GetGroupSums<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, string sumPropertyName) where T : new()
{
    //get the PropertyInfo you want to sum
    //var sumProp = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)memberExpression.Body).Operand).Member;
    var sumProp = typeof(T).GetProperty(sumPropertyName);
    //get all PropertyInfos that are not the property to sum
    var groupProps = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => x != sumProp).ToArray();

    //group them by a hash of non-summed properties (I got this hash method off StackExchange many years back)
    var groups = collection
        .GroupBy(x => GetHash(groupProps.Select(pi => pi.GetValue(x)).ToArray()))
        .Select(items =>
        {
            var item = new T();
            var firstItem = items.First();

            //clone the first item
            foreach (var gp in groupProps)
            {
                gp.SetValue(item, gp.GetValue(firstItem));
            }

            //Get a decimal sum and then convert back to the sum property type
            var sum = items.Sum(_item => (decimal)Convert.ChangeType(sumProp.GetValue(_item), typeof(decimal)));
            sumProp.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(sum, sumProp.PropertyType));

            //If it will always be int, just do this
            //var sum = items.Sum(_item => (int)sumProp.GetValue(_item));
            //sumProp.SetValue(item, sum);

            return item;
        });

    return groups.ToArray();
}

//I got this hash method off StackExchange many years back
public static int GetHash(params object[] args)
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        foreach (object arg in args)
        {
            hash = hash * 23 + arg.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
List<Element> elements = new List<Element>() {
    new Element() { no = 1, vendor = "a", Description =  "Nice", price = 10},
    new Element() { no = 2, vendor = "a", Description =  "Nice", price = 15},
    new Element() { no = 2, vendor = "b", Description =  "Nice", price = 10},
    new Element() { no = 1, vendor = "a", Description =  "Nice", price = 20}
};

var groups = GetGroupSums(elements, nameof(Element.price));
```

Comment: Nice hash formula! I hadn't considered that option.